# What does mean for all $t\in [0,1]$, $Z_t^n\to Z_t$ a.s.?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes

What does mean : for all $t\in [0,1]$, $Z_t^n\to Z_t$ a.s. ?

Does it mean that

**1)** $$\mathbb P\left(\forall t\in [0,1], \lim_{n\to \infty }Z_t^n=Z_t\right)=1$$

**2)** or $$\forall t\in [0,1], \ \ \mathbb P\left(\lim_{n\to \infty }Z_t^n=Z_t\right)=1.$$

Obviously, if **1)** hold, then so does **2)**. But the converse is wrong. But I think that **2)** should be written as $Z_t^n\to Z_t$ a.s. for all $t\in [0,1]$. But after all, *"for all $t\in [0,1]$, $Z_t^n\to Z_t$ a.s."* could also mean that if you fix $t\in [0,1]$ then $Z_t^n\to Z_t$ a.s. (i.e. **2)** holds).

I'm a bit confuse, because I often see that in some article/book, and I never know which one it is. Is there any rule ?

Comment: $\big\{\omega:\forall t\in [0,1], \lim_{n\to \infty }Z_t^n(\omega)=Z_t(\omega)\big\} = \bigcap_{t\in [0,1]}\big\{\omega:\lim_{n\to \infty }Z_t^n(\omega)=Z_t(\omega)\big\}$ is an uncountable intersection of members of the $\sigma$-algebra on which $\mathbb{P}$ is defined. So it may happen that $\mathbb{P}$ is not defined on this intersection. Therefore, it is option $\textbf{2}$, unless the process $\{Z_t\}$ has some additional properties and if it has the properties that enable to replace the uncountable intersection by countable one, then it is likely that both options are equivalent.

Comment: So, if $(Z_t^n)$ are continuous, both are equivalent ? ($(Z_t^{n})$ are continuous) @Slup

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the countability matters a lot here. Any set can be defined as measurable.
Anyway, back to your question, well, as you pointed out, two conclusions are different and your statement can be any one of those. So you should look up at your textbook again to find out what it is.
Either way, as you may know, if you provide some uniform-continuity (independent of n) for the sequence of processes $Z^n_t$, the two notions are equivalent.